# objectOf of array of object in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array:

```
const names = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "one"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "two"
    }
  ];
```

then in jsx I have to call a function which is outside of the loop.

```
const renderSomething = (obj: any) => obj.name + " "; //obj type should not be any
```

How can I declare `obj` equal to `objectOf names` in typescript?

demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-yvt0gj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the lazy way for typing

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const names = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "one"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "two"
    }
  ];
  const renderSomething = (obj: typeof names[0]) => obj.name + " "; //obj should not be any
  return <div className="App">{names.map((obj) => renderSomething(obj))}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `type` for your object. For example:

```js
type NameObject = {
  name: string;
  id: number;
};

export default function App() {
  const renderSomething = (obj: NameObject) => obj.name + " "; //obj should not be any

  const names: NameObject[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "one"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "two"
    }
  ];
  return <div className="App">{names.map((obj) => renderSomething(obj))}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles.css";

interface IUser {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
export default function App() {
  const names: IUser[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "one"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "two"
    }
  ];
  const renderSomething = (obj: IUser) => obj.name + " "; //obj should not be any
  return <div className="App">{names.map((obj) => renderSomething(obj))}</div>;
}
```

Comment: imagine you have huge arrays will you type them one by one?